# tqdm printing extra content at the start of a cycle

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm working on a simple batch iterator that should be able to keep track of the progress when running through a full set of values. For that I'm using tqdm, but at the start of an iteration it's printing empty content.

Code:

```
for start_idx in trange(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
    excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
```

Outputing something like:

```
Epoch: 0
100%|██████████| 1562/1562 [00:02<00:00, 630.24it/s]
  0%|          | 0/1562 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Epoch: 1
 62%|██████▏   | 965/1562 [00:01<00:00, 623.74it/s]
```

I've had similar issues with progressbar module and I just had to swap the type of output for `sys.stdout` but in this module I can't find a parameter to set that. Any suggestions?

Edit1: This is happening in PyCharm terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is that `Epoch: 1` at the end of the second line.

Somewhere in your code, you're printing that out, which throws `tqdm` off; it would usually use a `\r` (carriage return) character to return to the start of the line, but you're printing a newline character, so the previous line remains.

Comment: I'm using a `\r` when I print the "Epoch", it still happens sometimes, but not always at the same iteration.

Comment: Are you doing `print("Epoch {x}", end="\r")`, or `print("Epoch {x}\r")`? If the latter, there'll still be a \n.

Comment: Well, I managed to fix it by adding a `\r` right before the iteration begins, not the prettiest but I'll work for debugging. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You should probably look at the description/postfix features. https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#description-and-additional-stats

Comment: And since I come from C/C++ I always do \n\r as a terminator, but with the `end=`, it will still produce the same error, just the `print('\rEpoch:', epoch)` fixes the issue

Comment: But I'll check the postfix solution as it seems a bit more clean than what I'm doing. Thanks a lot!